# MYSQL | select inverse value between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I would like to SELECT the records from a table that have different values from another one.

Table 1.

```
+--------+-------+
| userID | tagID |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |     2 |
|      1 |     3 |
|      1 |     4 |
+--------+-------+
```

Table 2.

```
+---------+-------+
| ChaName | tagID |
+---------+-------+
| Hello   |     1 |
| How     |     2 |
| Are     |     3 |
| You     |     4 |
| Today   |     5 |
| Guys    |     6 |
| ?       |     7 |
+---------+-------+
```

And then it suppose to be

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| userID | tagID | chaNAME |
+--------+-------+---------+
|      1 |     1 | Hello   |
|      1 |     5 | Today   |
|      1 |     6 | Guys    |
|      1 |     7 | ?       |
+--------+-------+---------+
```

It looks very simple but I can't find the way to solve it.
Thank you for all of your answers <3

PS. btw i've tried to use ' not in ' but it got an error

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "not in" at position 92)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output, you need to use an `outer join`. A `left join` will give you all the records from left table `table2` and only matching records from right table `table1`. That means you will get `null` for records in `table1` which doesn't exist in `table2`. You can use this property in `where` clause to get only your expected records.

Also you cannot decide on `userid` on records in `table2`. If you want to hardcode them as `1`, then use `select 1 as userid, ...` in `select` clause.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe7b7/2)**</kbd>

```
select t2.tagid,t2.chaname
 from
table2 t2 left join table1 t1
on t1.tagid=t2.tagid
where t1.tagid is null
```

Comment: It returned an empty result  T.T

Comment: Give your exact table structure and query you used, so I can point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.userid,
       b.tagid,
       b.chaname 
from table1 a,table2 b 
where b.tagid not in (select tagid from tabel1)
```

Comment: Thank you @priyanshu btw I use phpmyadmin and it said it unrecognise not in :(